# Windows 7 unable to boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios

My system is working fine but when I want to format it from my Windows 7 Install Disk I am unable to do so.

My CD/DVD drive is reading CDs and DVDs fine in Windows, but when I restart my computer after inserting the Windows 7 Install Disk it restarts back into my Windows installation and the message "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD..." does not appear at any point. My Windows Disk is working in other systems, and prompts "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD" at the appropriate time during startup so my Windows disk must be fine.

What can I do on my machine about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of computers allow you to pick a temporary start-up device. Usually your computer goes to the hard drive to start up, loading the operating system.

However in this case, since you want to boot from the CD to install a clean copy of Windows 7, you will need to boot to the CD drive instead.

Your BIOS must have the HDD ahead of the CD-ROM. You can try one of the methods below:

1. When your computer boots up, tap the `F12` key a few times. If your BIOS supports it, it should bring up a menu to select a boot device. Using your arrow keys, highlight the `CD-ROM` or `DVD` drive entry and press enter. This will take you on your way to the Windows installation screen!

Otherwise...

1. Depending on your BIOS, you may need to press `F1, F2, DEL, ESC, F10, F11, or F12` to get to the BIOS setting screen.
2. From here you will need to find a menu that resembles `Boot Order` or `Boot Options` or `Boot Devices` or something of that nature
3. When you enter the `Boot Order` menu, move the `CD-ROM` device to the top of the order list. This will cause your BIOS to attempt to boot from the CD before the HDD if possible
4. Save & Quit, your machine will reboot with the new settings.

Hopefully this gets you going. If you provide the BIOS Make and Version number, or the type of computer you have (think brand here) I can make the instructions a bit more detailed.

Comment: I have tried both the methods but the message "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD..." does not appear..what can i do now..BIOS version/date : American megatrends inc. 0404, 1/7/2008.    SMBIOS Version : 2.4    thanks for any possible help.

Comment: Can you try `F8` to bring up the Boot selection menu when you see the very first screen from your bios? If that works, then try selecting the CD/DVD entry to boot the disk

Comment: i have tried it just a minute ago and a message appears
"please select BOOT device:
3M-WDC WD1600AABS-00H4A0
4M-TSST corp CDDVDW SH-S223F"
CD/DVD entry doesn't appears at all..
can i try to BOOT by BOOT-ABLE pen drive?

Comment: Alright, press the `F8` again to get that `Please Select BOOT device:` menu. Then choose the `CDDVDW SH-S223F` option. That is your CD, DVD drive :) After selecting this option, your computer should prompt you with the Windows `Press any key to boot from CD or DVD...`

Answer (score 4):

Enter your machine's BIOS and change the boot preference order  with CD/DVD ROM as first option . One of the following keys should lead you to your BIOS when you boot your machine.

F1

F2

DEL

ESC

F10